# Creating a JavaScript Quiz that shows answer explanation automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddler demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/natmit/7Du6N/

I have been pulling out my hair so any help from JavaScript/Jquery geniuses out there is much appreciated... I have already contacted the writer of this code and he has not replied.

I need help making the quiz do these things listed below:

1. After user clicks choice, show the explanation immediately
       without clicking "Check Answer".
2. I don't want the "Check Answer" button at all.
        The submit button should be hidden until user clicks
       choice, and then it should show labeled "Next Question" and on click, move to
       next question in quiz.
3. Move the explanation to display below the answer choices.
4. On the results page, I need a way to display one image if they
   scored 1-5 correct, and a different image if they scored 6-8 correct
   (assuming there are 8 questions total).

Thank you in advance,
N

```
var quiztitle = "Quiz Title";

/**
* Set the information about your questions here. The correct answer string needs to match
* the correct choice exactly, as it does string matching. (case sensitive)
*
*/
var quiz = [
    {
        "question"      :   "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
        "image"         :   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg/220px-Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg",
        "choices"       :   [
                                "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                "Albert Einstein",
                                "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                            ],
        "correct"       :   "Albert Einstein",
        "explanation"   :   "Albert Einstein drafted the special theory of relativity in 1905.",
    },
    {
        "question"      :   "Q2: Who is on the two dollar bill?",
        "image"         :   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/US_%242_obverse-high.jpg/320px-US_%242_obverse-high.jpg",
        "choices"       :   [
                                "Thomas Jefferson",
                                "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
                                "Benjamin Franklin",
                                "Abraham Lincoln"
                            ],
        "correct"       :   "Thomas Jefferson",
        "explanation"   :   "The two dollar bill is seldom seen in circulation. As a result, some businesses are confused when presented with the note.",
    },
    {
        "question"      :   "Q3: What event began on April 12, 1861?",
        "image"         :   "",
        "choices"       :   [
                                "First manned flight",
                                "California became a state",
                                "American Civil War began",
                                "Declaration of Independence"
                            ],
        "correct"       :   "American Civil War began",
        "explanation"   :   "South Carolina came under attack when Confederate soldiers attacked Fort Sumter. The war lasted until April 9th 1865.",
    },

];


/******* No need to edit below this line *********/
var currentquestion = 0, score = 0, submt=true, picked;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /**
     * HTML Encoding function for alt tags and attributes to prevent messy
     * data appearing inside tag attributes.
     */
    function htmlEncode(value){
      return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
    }

    /**
     * This will add the individual choices for each question to the ul#choice-block
     *
     * @param {choices} array The choices from each question
     */
    function addChoices(choices){
        if(typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array"){
            $('#choice-block').empty();
            for(var i=0;i<choices.length; i++){
                $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');                    
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets all of the fields to prepare for next question
     */
    function nextQuestion(){
        submt = true;
        $('#explanation').empty();
        $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
        $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
        if(quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != ""){
            if($('#question-image').length == 0){
                $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
            } else {
                $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
            }
        } else {
            $('#question-image').remove();
        }
        addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
        setupButtons();
    }

    /**
     * After a selection is submitted, checks if its the right answer
     *
     * @param {choice} number The li zero-based index of the choice picked
     */
    function processQuestion(choice){
        if(quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']){
            $('.choice').eq(choice).css({'background-color':'#50D943'});
            $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
            score++;
        } else {
            $('.choice').eq(choice).css({'background-color':'#D92623'});
            $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
        }
        currentquestion++;
        $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION &raquo;').on('click', function(){
            if(currentquestion == quiz.length){
                endQuiz();
            } else {
                $(this).text('Check Answer').css({'color':'#222'}).off('click');
                nextQuestion();
            }
        })
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the event listeners for each button.
     */
    function setupButtons(){
        $('.choice').on('mouseover', function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color':'#e1e1e1'});
        });
        $('.choice').on('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff'});
        })
        $('.choice').on('click', function(){
            picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
            $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
            $(this).css({'border-color':'#222','font-weight':700,'background-color':'#c1c1c1'});
            if(submt){
                submt=false;
                $('#submitbutton').css({'color':'#000'}).on('click', function(){
                    $('.choice').off('click');
                    $(this).off('click');
                    processQuestion(picked);
                });
            }
        })
    }

    /**
     * Quiz ends, display a message.
     */
    function endQuiz(){
        $('#explanation').empty();
        $('#question').empty();
        $('#choice-block').empty();
        $('#submitbutton').remove();
        $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
        $(document.createElement('h2')).css({'text-align':'center', 'font-size':'4em'}).text(Math.round(score/quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');
    }

    /**
     * Runs the first time and creates all of the elements for the quiz
     */
    function init(){
        //add title
        if(typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string"){
            $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
        } else {
            $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
        }

        //add pager and questions
        if(typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array"){
            //add pager
            $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id','pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
            //add first question
            $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
            //add image if present
            if(quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != ""){
                $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
            }
            $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id','explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

            //questions holder
            $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

            //add choices
            addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

            //add submit button
            $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('Check Answer').css({'font-weight':700,'color':'#222','padding':'30px 0'}).appendTo('#frame');

            setupButtons();
        }
    }

    init();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    /*css reset */
    html,body,div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,code,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,b,u,i{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0;} 
    article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;} 
    body{line-height:1; font:normal 0.9em/1em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;} 
    ol,ul{list-style:none;}
    strong{font-weight:700;}
    #frame{max-width:620px;width:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff;padding:10px;margin:3px;}
    h1{font:normal bold 2em/1.8em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid #999;padding:0;width:auto}
    h2{font:italic bold 1.3em/1.2em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;padding:0;text-align:center;margin:20px 0;}
    p.pager{margin:5px 0 5px; font:bold 1em/1em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#999;}
    img.question-image{display:block;max-width:250px;margin:10px auto;border:1px solid #ccc;width:100%;height:auto;}
    #choice-block{display:block;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
    #submitbutton{background:#5a6b8c;}
    #submitbutton:hover{background:#7b8da6;}
    #explanation{margin:0 auto;padding:20px;width:75%;}
    .choice-box{display:block;text-align:center;margin:8px auto;padding:10px 0;border:1px solid #666;cursor:pointer;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;}
</style>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Reduce your code to the essential and post a demo to reproduce the problem, and people might help you out.

Comment: Thanks eclanrs, working demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/natmit/7Du6N/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. On selecting an answer, it'll show the explanation for 3 seconds and will then move onto next question.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var quiztitle = "Social Security Quiz";


 var quiz = [
        {
            "question" : "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
            "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg/220px-Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                    "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                    "Albert Einstein",
                                    "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Albert Einstein",
            "explanation" : "Albert Einstein drafted the special theory of relativity in 1905.",
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q2: Who is on the two dollar bill?",
            "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/US_%242_obverse-high.jpg/320px-US_%242_obverse-high.jpg",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Thomas Jefferson",
                                    "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
                                    "Benjamin Franklin",
                                    "Abraham Lincoln"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Thomas Jefferson",
            "explanation" : "The two dollar bill is seldom seen in circulation. As a result, some businesses are confused when presented with the note.",
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q3: What event began on April 12, 1861?",
            "image" : "",
            "choices" : [
                                    "First manned flight",
                                    "California became a state",
                                    "American Civil War began",
                                    "Declaration of Independence"
                                ],
            "correct" : "American Civil War began",
            "explanation" : "South Carolina came under attack when Confederate soldiers attacked Fort Sumter. The war lasted until April 9th 1865.",
        },


    ];


 var currentquestion = 0,
     score = 0,
     submt = true,
     picked;

     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#submitbutton").hide();

     function htmlEncode(value) {
         return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
     }


     function addChoices(choices) {
         if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
             $('#choice-block').empty();
             for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                 $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
             }
         }
     }

     function nextQuestion() {
         submt = true;
         //alert("nQ");
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
         $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
         if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
             if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
                 $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
             } else {
                 $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
             }
         } else {
             $('#question-image').remove();
         }
         addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
         setupButtons();


     }


     function processQuestion() {

         //alert(choice);
         currentquestion++;
          //alert(currentquestion);
         $("#submitbutton").hide();

             if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                 endQuiz();
             } else {

                 nextQuestion();
             }

     }


     function setupButtons() {
         $('.choice').on('mouseover', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#e1e1e1'
             });
         });
         $('.choice').on('mouseout', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#fff'
             });
         })
         $('.choice').on('click', function () {
             //alert("");
             choice = $(this).attr('data-index');
             $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
             $(this).css({
                 'border-color': '#222',
                 'font-weight': 700,
                 'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
             });
             if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#50D943'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
             score++;
         } else {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#D92623'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
         }

             if (submt) {
                 //alert("submit");
                 submt = false;

                setTimeout(processQuestion,3000);

             }
         })
     }


     function endQuiz() {
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').empty();
         $('#choice-block').empty();
         $('#submitbutton').remove();
         $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
         $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
             'text-align': 'center',
             'font-size': '4em'
         }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');

         var result = Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100);
         var g = document.createElement('img');
          g.id = 'imgId';
          $(g).css({
             'height':'100px',
             'width': '100px',
             'margin-left':'40%'
         }).insertAfter('#explanation');

         if(result < 33){
            $("#imgId").attr("src","http://www.chaaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/fail.jpg");
         }
         else if(result < 67){
            $("#imgId").attr("src","http://www.ytechie.com/2008/04/how-does-your-boss-know-youre-doing-a-great-job/good-job.png");
         }
          else if(result < 100){
            $("#imgId").attr("src","http://www.ytechie.com/2008/04/how-does-your-boss-know-youre-doing-a-great-job/good-job.png");
         }
         else if(result == 100){
            $("#imgId").attr("src","http://www.getaheadinmarketing.com/wp-content/themes/myjournal/js/timthumb.php?src=http://www.getaheadinmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/evaluation-tick.jpg&w=653&h=260");
         }
     }


     function init() {
         //add title
         if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
             $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
         } else {
             $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
         }

         //add pager and questions
         if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
             //add pager
             $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
             //add first question
             $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
             //add image if present
             if (quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != "") {
                 $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
             }

             //questions holder
             $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

             //add choices
             addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

              $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

             setupButtons();

         }
     }

     init();
 });    


    </script>
```

Comment: this is just what I needed to address issue #4 in my question. I may need to do something different with the "next" instead of auto-advance, but this has helped tremendously. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the code here -

```
var quiztitle = "Social Security Quiz";


 var quiz = [
    {
        "question" : "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
        "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg/220px-Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg",
        "choices" : [
                                "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                "Albert Einstein",
                                "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                            ],
        "correct" : "Albert Einstein",
        "explanation" : "Albert Einstein drafted the special theory of relativity in 1905.",
    },
    {
        "question" : "Q2: Who is on the two dollar bill?",
        "image" : "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/US_%242_obverse-high.jpg/320px-US_%242_obverse-high.jpg",
        "choices" : [
                                "Thomas Jefferson",
                                "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
                                "Benjamin Franklin",
                                "Abraham Lincoln"
                            ],
        "correct" : "Thomas Jefferson",
        "explanation" : "The two dollar bill is seldom seen in circulation. As a result, some businesses are confused when presented with the note.",
    },
    {
        "question" : "Q3: What event began on April 12, 1861?",
        "image" : "",
        "choices" : [
                                "First manned flight",
                                "California became a state",
                                "American Civil War began",
                                "Declaration of Independence"
                            ],
        "correct" : "American Civil War began",
        "explanation" : "South Carolina came under attack when Confederate soldiers attacked Fort Sumter. The war lasted until April 9th 1865.",
    },


];


 var currentquestion = 0,
 score = 0,
 submt = true,
 picked;

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submitbutton").hide();

 function htmlEncode(value) {
     return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
 }


 function addChoices(choices) {
     if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
         $('#choice-block').empty();
         for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
             $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
         }
     }
 }

 function nextQuestion() {
     submt = true;
     alert("nQ");
     $('#explanation').empty();
     $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
     $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
     if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
         if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
             $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
         } else {
             $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
         }
     } else {
         $('#question-image').remove();
     }
     addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
     setupButtons();


 }


 function processQuestion(choice) {
     alert(choice);
     currentquestion++;
      alert(currentquestion);
     $("#submitbutton").hide();

         if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
             endQuiz();
         } else {

             nextQuestion();
         }

 }


 function setupButtons() {
     $('.choice').on('mouseover', function () {
         $(this).css({
             'background-color': '#e1e1e1'
         });
     });
     $('.choice').on('mouseout', function () {
         $(this).css({
             'background-color': '#fff'
         });
     })
     $('.choice').on('click', function () {
         alert("");
         choice = $(this).attr('data-index');
         $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
         $(this).css({
             'border-color': '#222',
             'font-weight': 700,
             'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
         });
         if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
         $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
             'background-color': '#50D943'
         });
         $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
         score++;
     } else {
         $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
             'background-color': '#D92623'
         });
         $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
     }
            $("#submitbutton").show();
         if (submt) {
             alert("submit");
             submt = false;
             $('#submitbutton').css({
                 'color': '#000'

             });
             $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
               alert("click");
                  $('.choice').off('click');
                 $(this).off('click');
                 processQuestion(choice);
             });
         }
     })
 }


 function endQuiz() {
     $('#explanation').empty();
     $('#question').empty();
     $('#choice-block').empty();
     $('#submitbutton').remove();
     $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
     $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
         'text-align': 'center',
         'font-size': '4em'
     }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');
 }


 function init() {
     //add title
     if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
         $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
     } else {
         $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
     }

     //add pager and questions
     if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
         //add pager
         $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
         //add first question
         $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
         //add image if present
         if (quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != "") {
             $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
         }
         $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

         //questions holder
         $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

         //add choices
         addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

         //add submit button
         $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('Check Answer').css({
             'font-weight': 700,
             'color': '#222',
             'padding': '30px 0',
          }).appendTo('#frame');


       $("#submitbutton").hide();
         setupButtons();
     }
 }

 init();
});
```

working fiddler:- http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/6/

Comment: Thanks monu, that didn't quite work. My demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/natmit/7Du6N/

Comment: @user3357416 - check I have updated above code. It will according to your requirement. Accept the answer if it help you.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Do you know is it possible to keep the user from switching their answer? I want them not to be able to click on the other choices once they click one choice.
Thank you!

Comment: @user3357416 mark the answer so that it helps others.

Comment: the code worked (items 1 and 2 resolved in my original question) after I commented out the alerts @monu added.