# Get rid of check answer button in this javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a quiz and i want this "check answer" button to be removed and on click of any choice answer must be displayed.

Can anyone please help me how to do it?

I've found a duplicate here, 
[Creating a JavaScript Quiz that shows answer explanation automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061733/creating-a-javascript-quiz-that-shows-answer-explanation-automatically)
But this is not what i'm trying to do. since I'm new to stack overflow I can't comment on this question so opening this fresh one.

Here is JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/natmit/7Du6N/

```
   function processQuestion(choice) {
        if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
            $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                'background-color': '#84e47b'
            });
            $('#explanation').html('<h5>Awesome! Right answer!</h5><br/>' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
            score++;
        } else {
            $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                'background-color': '#e0514e'
            });
            $('#explanation').html('<h3>Oops! wrong answer</h3><br/>' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
        }
        currentquestion++;
        $('#submitbutton').html('<h4>NEXT QUESTION &raquo;</h4>').on('click', function() {
            if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                endQuiz();
            } else {
                $(this).text('CHECK ANSWER').css({
                    'color': '#ffffff'
                }).off('click');
                nextQuestion();

            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: [`$('#submitbutton').hide();`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Hi, I'm new to javascript, can you please tell me where to call this and will the choices work automatically and show results if i just hide the submit button?

Comment: Hello, Raju. If you could please explain what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve or show an example that does what you want, it would greatly help in helping you.

Comment: when user selects an option right, he should see next question, and when he selects a wrong answer, he should see what?

Comment: His choice might be either wrong or right, He should see answer  and a button to go next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `$('#submitbutton').hide();` at the end of your init() function.

Change the actions of your Buttons in your setupButtons() function somewhat like this:

```
     $('.choice').on('click', function () {
         picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
         $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
         $(this).css({
             'border-color': '#222',
             'font-weight': 700,
             'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
         });
          processQuestion(picked);
     });
```

At the end of your processQuestion() function show the button again with `$('#submitbutton').show();` and finally hide the button again at the end of your nextQuestion() function with `$('#submitbutton').hide();`

Here a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ft4sy7s/

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks very much. You saved my day. I appreciate your time and efforts help me out. 
God bless

Comment: @RajuLOCM This script allows the user to carry on clicking answers after an answer has been selected.

Comment: If you click 3 answers on the first question it will break the script when you click "next question".

Comment: I've tested it on more than 30 questions in my quiz, its working Good. on fiddle we have only 3 questions to answer. 

I'll check once again with yours sir. Thanks very much

Comment: @RajuLOCM The main issue is that you can carry on clicking answers after an answer has been selected. This isn't geat from a usability/visual perspective, but it also adds to a counter which will mess up when the script thinks it has got to the last question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is change this code inside your `setupButtons()` function from this:

```
$('.choice').on('click', function () {
 picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
 $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
 $(this).css({
   'border-color': '#222',
   'font-weight': 700,
   'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
 });
 if (submt) {
   submt = false;
   $('#submitbutton').css({
     'color': '#000'
   }).on('click', function () {
     $('.choice').off('click');
     $(this).off('click');
     processQuestion(picked);
   });
 }
})
```

to:

```
$('.choice').on('click', function () {
    if (submt) {
        submt = false;
        picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
        $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
        $(this).css({
            'border-color': '#222',
            'font-weight': 700,
            'background-color': '#c1c1c1'
        });
        $('.choice').css({
          'cursor': 'default'
        });

        processQuestion(picked);
        $('#submitbutton').css({
            'color': '#000'
        });
    }
})
```

All I am doing here is taking the `processQuestion()` function outside of the `$('#submitbutton')` click event, so it is triggered as soon as a choice is selected.

I have also moved the rest of the jQuery code that was inside the `$('.choice')` click event and moved it inside the `if (submt)` conditional statement. This prevents the answer selection CSS being activated after an answer has been selected.

I added the CSS of `cursor:default` to the options after an option is selected, just so it is clear to the user that they can't select any more.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/326/

**UPDATED FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/328/ *process answer button hidden

Comment: Thanks so much but when i go to your fiddle "check answer button" was still there. 

I'll be more specific with my questions next time. Really appreciate your time for me.

Comment: Thanks so much, Its great now

Comment: @RajuLOCM No problem. Please mark answer as useful ;)